# ElasticSearch container on CoreOS with persistent storage

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, coreos

I'm trying to run an [ElasticSearch](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/elasticsearch) cluster on Docker and CoreOS [stable] on DigitalOcean. To get persistent storage working, I tried pretty much every option and running out of ideas.

Pretty much every --volume option (`-v /data/elasticsearch`, `-v $(pwd)/esdata:/data/elasticsearch`, ...) is ignored and in the logs it says `using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/vda9)]]`.

Only when using `-v /usr/share/elasticsearch/data:/data/elasticsearch` I get an error saying it can't write on a read-only file system.

What am I doing wrong?

The full elasticsearch.service is:

```
[Unit]
Description=ElasticSearch service
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutSec=180
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment

ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /data/elasticsearch
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull elasticsearch

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '\
  curl -f ${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}:4001/v2/keys/services/elasticsearch; \
  if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then \
      UNICAST_HOSTS=$(etcdctl ls --recursive /services/elasticsearch \
                      | sed "s/\/services\/elasticsearch\///g" \
                      | sed "s/$/:9300/" \
                      | paste -s -d","); \
  else \
      UNICAST_HOSTS=""; \
  fi; \
  /usr/bin/docker run \
    -v /data/elasticsearch \
    --name %p-%i \
    --net=host \
    elasticsearch \
    --node.name=%p-%i \
    --cluster.name=mysearchcluster \
    --network.publish_host=${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4} \
    --discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled=false \
    --discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=$UNICAST_HOSTS'

ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop %p-%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker rm %p-%i

[X-Fleet]
X-Conflicts=%p@*.service
```

Answer (score 1):

Running on a single node, ElasticSearch didn't put anything into /data/elasticsearch. The moment I deployed multiple nodes, there was data and it seems persistent. The final .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=ElasticSearch service
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutSec=180
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment

ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /data/elasticsearch
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull elasticsearch

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '\
  curl -f ${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}:4001/v2/keys/services/elasticsearch; \
  if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then \
      UNICAST_HOSTS=$(etcdctl ls --recursive /services/elasticsearch \
                      | sed "s/\/services\/elasticsearch\///g" \
                      | sed "s/$/:9300/" \
                      | paste -s -d","); \
  else \
      UNICAST_HOSTS=""; \
  fi; \
  /usr/bin/docker run \
    --volume /data/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data \
    --name %p-%i \
    --net=host \
    elasticsearch \
    --node.name=%p-%i \
    --cluster.name=myescluster \
    --network.publish_host=${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4} \
    --discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled=false \
    --discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=$UNICAST_HOSTS'

ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop %p-%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker rm %p-%i

[X-Fleet]
X-Conflicts=%p@*.service
```